# Indexing nested documents giving back parents when asking for children

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm wondering if I missed something in my code:

```
public class Main {

private SolrClient client1;

public void run() {
    client1 = new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr").build();

    SolrInputDocument doc1 = new SolrInputDocument();

    doc1.addField("id", "1");
    doc1.addField("type_s", "up");
    SolrInputDocument doc2 = new SolrInputDocument();

    doc2.addField("id", "2");
    doc2.addField("type_s", "down");

    doc1.addChildDocument(doc2);

    SolrInputDocument doc4 = new SolrInputDocument();
    doc4.addField("id", "4");
    doc4.addField("type_s", "up");

    SolrInputDocument doc5 = new SolrInputDocument();
    doc5.addField("id", "5");
    doc5.addField("type_s", "down");

    doc4.addChildDocument(doc5);

    try {
        client1.add("techproducts", Arrays.asList(doc1,doc4));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Indexing failed" + e);
    }
}
```

If I start Solr 6.3 using bin/start start -e techproduct and ask the following:

http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/select?fl=*,[child%20parentFilter=type_s:down]&fq=type_s:down&indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json

then I get:

```
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "type_s": "down"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "type_s": "down",
      "_childDocuments_": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "type_s": "up"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

which seems to be a bug for me. Or did I miss something?

Notice that the relations "2 is a child of 1" and "5 is a child of 4" are working fine. It's just that I get extra (unwanted) relations.

Comment: did you ever find more about this? We've seen something similar but retrieving parents filtered by children fields in 6.6. Now for our case it seems to happen in very special conditions and a rate of 1 out of 50-100 indexed documents. Like you mentioned in a thread elsewhere, the issue isn't reproduced when doing commits after every change.

We had fiddler captures of all posted data, so we did track the data was posted correctly in our case.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find more about this. I simply gave up with parent/children relations and flatten everything I can

Comment: ok. Was your case exactly as posted? No deletes or updates to the documents that remove child documents? In our case we also had some deletes ran as commands in the same post, and it turned out to be that if the delete of the parent appears before the delete of the children then it could race with soft commits (via commitWithin) and the deleted child document would survive as a child of a completely unrelated document.